# Error al invocar modulo en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grunt

Estoy tratando de usar grunt para mi app en angularjs.
tengo mi archivo app.js de la siguiente manera:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    angular.module('starter',['starter.features.controllers', 'starter.services', 'starter.directives'])

.......
})();
```

en él llamo a mi modulo starter.features.controllers

```
angular.module('starter.features.controllers', ['ui.router', 'ngResource']);
```

sin grunt todo sale bien pero al ejecutar el comando grunt me sale este error:

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=starter.features.controllers
```

uso grunt para minificar mi app estos node_modules uso

```
grunt-contrib-concat grunt-contrib-cssmin grunt-contrib-uglify grunt-processhtml
```

como puedo resolver dicho error?

de antemano les agradezco

Comment: Aun sigues con tu problema? trato de buscar una soluciona  tu problema.

Comment: Hola si lo solucione, minificando en orden a mis librerias por ejemplo angularjs, controllers, directivas etc